# How to create a new file from Form Data with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, file

### A Solution has been found! (I would still like to talk to @Joel Cox though!)

---

***Here's the code that managed to achieve what I was asking for!***

By using fopen() and fwrite() I was able to generate a file with values from the HTML Form POST method. Here's the code for that!

```
$myfile = fopen("/path/to/file" , "w") or die("Unable to open file!"); //this will create the file if it doesn't exist
$txt = isset($_POST["--INPUT NAME--"]) ? $_POST["--INPUT NAME--"] . "\n" : ''; //this will get the data from selected input
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
```

### Original Question

So here's my circumstance, I have a web form with text inputs, checkboxes and dropdown lists, the usual. What I want to do then is when the users submits all this data, it will create a new file and allow it to be downloaded. I have tried many methods but I seem to not quite get it right, I am no pro with PHP and I have only become decent at the language for a few months, so, some guidance here would be great! Below are images of what I want to achieve.

***User selects data which will be submitted;***

[image: Data]

***Data is handled using PHP and creates a new file to download***

[image]

So, to recap, user selects/inputs data, on clicking "submit" in the HTML Form, the data is processed with php by adding all the data into a new file and saving it, allowing it to be downloaded.

I hope I have explained my problem well, I am in no way trying to be lazy and get someone to do the code for me, I just need some guidance as I have searched everywhere and cannot seem to get what I need. All help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: which is the part you have trouble with? Ask a question, please.

Comment: I guess you're pretty new to PHP?
The ?...: in there is the "ternary" operator. it allows you to evaluate a condition and provide a different value for a truthy or falsy value. In this case, put whatever you want for your "else" case in between the two single quotes at the end of that line.

Comment: @JoelCox Yeah, wasn't familiar with that part of the code! Thanks!:)

Comment: @JoelCox Whatever I put into the single quotes at the end of that line doesn't work :( For example, `$txt = isset($_POST["port"]) ? $port . $_POST["port"] . "\n" : '$port . "25565"';`the "25565" doesn't get added to the variable $port if there is no data!

Comment: I think what you want for that line is `$txt = (isset($_POST['port']) ? $_POST['port'] : '25565')."\n";`

Comment: No that didn't seem to work. The variable `$port` contains a string `"server-port="`, what I was hoping for is if the user hasn't submitted any data into the text field, it would default to a certain number.

Comment: Would you like to chat and I can show you my code?

Comment: TBH I'm not sure how to start a chat. I'm still in the chat from earlier from the comments on my answer though - feel free to continue discussion there.

Thanks for the extra explanation of your $port variable. Try `$txt = $port.(isset($_POST['port']) ? $_POST['port'] : '25565')."\n";`

Comment: I'll continue on the old chat :) the code you gave again doesn't work, it still shows up blank in the text file :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pointing you in the right direction here.
Use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to save your data to a file, then either give people a link to said file which your webserver will serve, or use

```
header('Location: /path/to/file');
```

to redirect them to it.

Comment: Okay, thank you, also, before using `file_put_contents`, is it possible to copy the said file, save it, and then use the `file_put_contents` ?

Comment: You're trying to create a file right? so put all the data you want in the file into a single variable (use "\n" for newline character), then use file_put_contents to save that file to the server, and give the user a link to the file or redirect them to it.

Comment: While what you're saying makes sense to me, I am not that experienced with handling files using PHP, so thanks for the help! I'll see what I can do..

Comment: Ok. If you're having trouble with a specific error that you're getting while trying these things, that'll be a better kind of question to ask here. Essentially with what you've asked so far it doesn't appear that you've done any research of tried anything yourself yet. Happy to help more if you have a more specific question about a certain problem or error, rather than a general question asking "how would I go about accomplishing X". Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah I understand, I did make the situation a lot more difficult for myself. I had originally used methods that would copy an original file, append text to it, and then save it using a random name. But, like you suggested, I can simply create the file. I do have one question though, will the user created file get overridden if another user goes through the same steps?

Comment: That depends on how you save the files. You could use the php uniqid function to generate a unique id that can be included in each filename, which would mean your data directory would slowly fill with these files as more people submitted the form. Alternately if you don't actually need the files on the server to be kept, there's some cool stuff you can do by using php://output as the file you write to - essentially you could write your file directly to the browser output stream, combined with the right http headers will download the file without even having it saved on the server.

Comment: Let me know if you would like more information on the above things.

Comment: The second option seems pretty cool and efficient, any help on that?:) The first option, I could just run a script which would delete all files in a certain directory, to keep it from getting clogged up. But the second option seems better!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67443/discussion-between-mynameisnotsocool-and-joel-cox).

Comment: Can we discuss this in chat? Really need help  and it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hey - sorry I'm at work at the moment and will be heading home shortly.  Will be back online about an hour from now and can chat then if you're still around?

Comment: Ooops, my bad! Yes, I'll be around! Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

just as @joel said ,

u can use **file_get_content** & **file_put_content** which take care of everything like create the file if it doesnt exist , open the file > add the data > close the file + having more options like *FILE_APPEND* and all of that in just a couple of lines of code.

Comment: That's great! As you can see, I have managed to get what I wanted (Sort of!) All I need to know now is how would I rename the file without saving it to the server? (I want to do this so that there are no overwriting of files!) Any ideas?

Comment: u can check if the file exist first by file_exists(the file name) and if it does then save the new filename with either a name u want or maybe using something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle.php + the name u want , btw the same approach works with file upload.

Comment: @MyNameIsNotSoCool I put some more information for you in the chat thread attached to the comments on my answer as well.

Answer (score -2):

This is what i did and it helped

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      float: left
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>y<h1>o</h1><h2>u</h2><p>are</p><h1><abbr title="cool">::::</abbr></h1></h2>
</body>   
</html>
```